# Setting MIX_ENV in Heroku for Phoenix Framework

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I've instantiated two Heroku apps successfully: my-app-prod and my-app-test. There are specific environment variables I've configured in the Heroku app settings. I am using the standard configuration files in Phoenix: config.exs, test.exs, prod.exs, dev.exs.

After configuring my-app-test in Heroku with the app variable MIX_ENV=test,  it is still loading variables from prod.exs.

Are there any additional steps I'm missing so that my app uses test.exs?

I followed all the instructions here: 
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/heroku.html

When I run git push, I can verify it's using prod.exs based on the following output.

```html
remote: Generated my_phoenix_app_name app
remote: -----> Creating .profile.d with env vars
remote: -----> Writing export for multi-buildpack support
remote: -----> Executing post compile: pwd
remote: /tmp/build_f5b9e6e5890fcb58b9689f433c554c6a
remote: -----> Phoenix app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Loading configuration and environment
remote:        Loading config...
remote:        Detecting assets directory
remote:        * package.json found in custom directory
remote:        Will use phoenix configuration:
remote:        * assets path .
remote:        * mix tasks namespace phoenix
remote:        Will use the following versions:
remote:        * Node 5.3.0
remote:        Will export the following config vars:
remote: CLIENT_ID
remote: DATABASE_URL
remote: POOL_SIZE
remote: SECRET_KEY_BASE
remote: SHOPIFY_SECRET
remote:        * MIX_ENV=prod
```

Comment: It sounds like it is storing the variables at compile time. Are you running the app with `mix phoenix.server` or using a distillery release?

Comment: Updated post, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildpack for Elixir is setting `MIX_ENV` to `prod` [by default](https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir/blob/master/lib/misc_funcs.sh#L60), so you don't actually need this setting in your Procfile. You can change it simply to:

```
web: mix phoenix.server
```

On `my-app-prod` you don't have to do anything. On `my-app-test` just set `MIX_ENV` to `test`. You can use command line

```
heroku config:set MIX_ENV=test --app my-app-test
```

If it does not work, try to redeploy your apps to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Procfile` where it says:

```
web: MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server
```

you should be able to change it to:

```
web: mix phoenix.server
```

since you are already setting `MIX_ENV` in the app's settings config vars you should be able to just leave that MIX_ENV part off.

Comment: My repo has only one Procfile. How do I manage multiple environments this way?

Comment: @sheldonkreger Have you tried leaving off the `MIX_ENV=prod` part of the Procfile? since you;re setting the MIX_ENV in your heroku config